# How to make Prettier STOP DELETE "space lines" after a declaration?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

This space:
[image: before]

... is being removed by Prettier:
[image: after]

EDIT: Already checked their docs, there is nothing there.